delete line under condition R dplyr
I have a df like this one:



ID
FOLLOW-UP
RECURRENCE
RECURRENCE DATE




15
1
no



15
2
yes
2003-05-15


16
1
no



29
1
yes
2002-06-10


29
2
yes
2002-12-16


34
1
yes
2009-11-15


34
2
no



34
3
yes
2012-05-03


36
1
no



36
2
no




With in the first column the patient identifier (ID), in the 2nd the follow-up number, in the 3rd column the occurrence of a recurrence (yes/no) and in the last column the date of recurrence (if recurrence = yes).
There are therefore repeated lines for several patients, if they have several follow-ups.
I'd like to obtain a df with only 1 line per patient.

If the patient has had several recurrences, I'd like to keep the line with the oldest recurrence (date of first recurrence).
If the patient has had several follow-ups with recurrence and without recurrence, I'd like to keep the line with the (oldest) recurrence.
If the patient has several follow-ups without recurrence, I'd like to keep follow-up 1.

In the end, I'd like to get this df here:



ID
FOLLOW_UP
RECURRENCE
RECURRENCE_DATE




15
2
yes
2003-05-15


16
1
no



29
1
yes
2002-06-10


34
1
yes
2009-11-15


36
1
no




Here's a reproducible example :
df <- data.frame(ID = c("15", "15", "16","29", "29", "34","34", "34", "36","36"),
                 FOLLOW_UP = c("1", "2", "1","1", "2", "1","2", "3", "1","2"),
                 RECURRENCE = c("no", "yes", "no","yes", "yes", "yes","no", "yes", "no","no"),
                 RECURRENCE_DATE = c("", "2003-05-15", "","2002-06-10", "2002-12-16", "2009-11-15","", "2012-05-03", "","")
)

I thought of using the “group by” and “slice” functions but I don't know how to apply them with conditions.
Thanks in advance

something like this:
df$RECURRENCE_DATE <- as.Date(df$RECURRENCE_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df_filtered <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(RECURRENCE), RECURRENCE_DATE, FOLLOW_UP) %>%  
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()


You could slice twice:
slice_min(df, RECURRENCE_DATE, by=ID) |>
  slice_min(FOLLOW_UP, by=ID)

  ID FOLLOW_UP RECURRENCE RECURRENCE_DATE
1 15         2        yes      2003-05-15
2 16         1         no            <NA>
3 29         1        yes      2002-06-10
4 34         1        yes      2009-11-15
5 36         1         no            <NA>

Note I datified your RECURRENCE_DATE
df <- mutate(df, RECURRENCE_DATE=as.Date(RECURRENCE_DATE))

